# Addgroup: command not found

Tags: sudo, path

I'm following [this tutorial](https://gist.github.com/joshellington/2224420) to setup a new sftp user on a webserver running on debian, but when I get to step 3

```
sudo addgroup filetransfer
```

I can't go on because the terminal gives me the following error

```
Addgroup: command not found
```

I installed the adduser package with `apt-get install` and the server says it's already installed. I also tried to use the command `groupadd` but nothing changes.
What am I doing wrong? 
Thanks everyone!

EDIT: the result of `sudo bash -c 'echo $PATH'` as asked in the questions below

```
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games
```

Comment: What happens when you try `sudo groupadd filetransfer` a second time? The `groupadd` utility does not provide verbose output, but does when the group already exists.

Comment: Please run the following command and include it and its result in your question. `sudo bash -c 'echo $PATH'`

Comment: Also the result of running `sudo grep -i secure_path /etc/sudoers`

Comment: roaima, I added the result of the first command in the question, the second command didn't give any result. thanks!

Comment: Lambert, if I run it a second time it gives the same output: command not found.

Comment: Strange, but you can try using the full path for example `sudo /usr/sbin/groupadd filetransfer`. Use `which groupadd` to get the location of the utility, if available.

Comment: `groupadd` != `addgroup`. Try `groupadd`.

Comment: @Kusalananda already tried, but it gives me the same output: command not found.
@Lambert `which` doesn't give any output

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It looks like your environment doesn't include the `/usr/sbin` directory that holds such system programs.

The quick fix should be to use `/usr/sbin/adduser` instead of just `adduser`.

Two alternative solutions are:

1. Change the `PATH` in `.bashrc` and/or `.bash_profile` so that `/usr/sbin` is included in the list. For example, here is my setting:

   ```
   export PATH="$HOME/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games"
   ```
2. Edit the `sudoers` configuration (with `sudo visudo -f /etc/sudoers.d/securepath`) and add this line to the empty file:

   ```
   # Extend the PATH for sudo commands
   Defaults secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"
   ```

Either would be sufficient.

Comment: @Ada which solution (of the three) did you use?