# -bash: ifconfig: command not found when using `su - redbox -c 'ifconfig'`

Tags: bash, su, alpine-linux

I am logged in as root user and need to execute a single command from redbox user without switching. For this, I am using following command:

`# su - redbox -c 'CMD'`.

When I try to execute "ifconfig" (`su - redbox -c 'ifconfig'`), I get following error:

> -bash: ifconfig: command not found

But it works if I switch to redbox first, and then execute "ifconfig" as shown below:

`# su - redbox
 $ ifconfig`

Same problem for many more commands. I don't understand what is causing this problem.
Please help me figure it out.

I am using Alpine Linux v3.9.4

**UPDATE:**

Thanks to link shared by Jeff, I see the problem now. When I use `su - redbox - c 'ifconfig'`, the value of $PATH is different than when I use `su - redbox` followed by `ifconfig`.

Can someone explain why $PATH is different in both cases? Note that in both cases I hove used `-` which uses login shell.

Comment: This is almost https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/29791/5132 .

Comment: @JdeBP Thats not true. If you observe, I have used '-' to specify that bash needs to start as login shell. But it still creates problem.

Comment: Ahem!  I distinctly wrote _almost_.

Comment: @JdeBP Point taken. But you got to agree that solution does not help me a least bit.

Comment: You are not the only person that this WWW site targets.  This is a public Q&A WWW site, not a personal helpdesk.  Sometimes we point to other related stuff so that _other people_ can find it.

Comment: @NirajJoshi are you adverse to just running `/usr/sbin/ifconfig` instead of `ifconfig`?

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/356105/117549 and https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/232782/117549

Comment: Thanks @Jeff. Linked questions helped a bit in understanding the problem. And ifconfig is just an example. I want to know why there is difference in those two ways.

Answer (score 0):

Read `man sudoers`. `sudo` forces its idea of `$PATH` on the commands it executes.

```
sudo -u redbox -c $( type -p ifconfig)
```

to use your `$PATH` or

```
sudo -u redbox /usr/sbin/ifconfig
```

Comment: I am not using sudo though.